# saving extracted statistic from regression in a dataset: Stata

Tags: stata

I wonder if you could help me figure it out a quite simple question of how I can save an extracted statistic from a regression in a separate dataset (or file), and also add more statistics from the other regression to it later?

For example, the statistic from one regression can be extracted as e(f) and from another one is also as e(f).

Answer (score 0):

Roger Newson's `parmest` is great for dealing with "[resulsets](http://www.stata.com/meeting/10uk/Newson_overhead.pdf)," which are Stata datasets created from the output of a Stata command. The help file has a nice example of combining three regressions into a single file that I modified here to include R^2 [stored in e(df_r)]:

```
sysuse auto, clear

tempfile tf1 tf2 tf3
parmby "reg price weight", lab saving(`"`tf1'"', replace) idnum(1) idstr(M1) escal(r2)
parmby "reg price foreign", lab saving(`"`tf2'"', replace) idnum(2) idstr(M2) escal(r2)
parmby "reg price weight foreign", lab saving(`"`tf3'"', replace) idnum(3) idstr(M3) escal(r2)

drop _all
append using `"`tf1'"' `"`tf2'"' `"`tf3'"'
list idnum idstr es_1, noobs nodis
```